# Port 0x6F problem

Tags: arduino-mega

When I disassemble an Arduino IDE created pjoject I see in the created code ("disassembled code actually"), the it uses IN / OUT instruction on port 0X6F.

Like this (part of disassembled list):

```
00E3     4FFF                SBCI      R31,0XFF                 ; .O
00E4     91A5                LPM       R26,Z+                   ; ..
00E5     91B4                LPM       R27,Z                    ; ..
00E6     B79F                IN        R25,0X6F                 ; ..
00E7     94F8                CLI                                ; ..
00E8     1161                CPSE      R22,R1                   ; a.
00E9     C004                RJMP      L00EE                    ; ..

00EA     918C                LD        R24,X                    ; ..
00EB     9530                COM       R19                      ; 0.
00EC     2338                AND       R19,R24                  ; 8#
00ED     C002                RJMP      L00F0                    ; ..

00EE     91EC      L00EE:    LD        R30,X                    ; ..
00EF     2B3E                OR        R19,R30                  ; >+
00F0     933C      L00F0:    ST        X,R19                    ; <.
00F1     BF9F                OUT       0X6F,R25                 ; ..
00F2     9508      L00F2:    RET
```

Anyway the ATMEGA328 Datasheet says that port 0x6F is memorymapped and as such should be accessed through LDS/STS instructions.  This problem really confuses me.  Can anyone give me an explanation ??  Thanks !

Comment: What is the original C/C++ code?

Comment: avr-objdump disassembles those bytes to `in r25, 0x3f` and `out 0x3f, r25`, which is consistent with Mikael Patel's answer. It looks like your disassembler is broken.

Answer (score 4):

The AVR operation code for the IN instruction is:

```
Loads data from the I/O Space (Ports, Timers, Configuration Registers, etc.) into register Rd in the Register File.

Operation:
(i) Rd ← I/O(A)
Syntax: Operands: Program Counter:
(i) IN Rd,A 0 ≤ d ≤ 31, 0 ≤ A ≤ 63, PC ← PC + 1
16-bit Opcode: 1011 0AAd dddd AAAA
```

The disassemble of the operation code `B79F (hex) = 1011 0111 1001 1111 (bin)` is `IN R25,$3F` which is actually `SREG`.

The block of code with the `IN, CLI` and `OUT` instruction is a critical section where the flags in `SREG` are saved, interrupts are turned off, and later the `SREG` is restored.

Cheers!

Comment: Thansk a lot . I'll check with the Disasm creator, tell him the problem and recompile when I get a new version.. Hope that solves the problem.   Anyway many, many thanks for the constructive answers.

Comment: HI: (time 22:23 European  time):   Called him, told him about the error. He examined. Corrected it. Returned a new version. I ran it. Disassembled the file (which give the above list), io-ports are now correct (all in range 0x00 - 0x6F) Thank for a valuable help.  KSH